# Deleting the last node in the linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

Please can you explain to me how this function deletes the last node in a single linked list

```
void deleend()
{

    Node *q;
    Node *p;

    for (q = head; q != NULL; q = q->next) 
    {
        p=q;
        p->next=NULL;
    }
    delete q;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. It doesn't work at all. It unlinks *all* nodes in the list, and then you try to `delete` a null pointer. You should learn how to use a debugger, then you can step through the code line by line to see what it really does.

Comment: @Joachim: Actually I believe, it unlinks only the connection from the first to the second node.

Comment: actually it unlinks only the first node. `q = head; p = q; p->next = NULL`. Next iteration: `q = q->next` means `q = null` and thus exits the loop right?

Comment: @MikeMB You're right, well, *almost*... :) It unlinks the first node, and then the loop ends after the first iteration. So the OP is left with a stray list which can't be reached, and a single-node list is left with `head` pointing to that single node.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, thats what I meant. In any case, it certainly doesn't even remotely do what the OP was made to believe it does.

Comment: As @FredMaggiowski already said. It's a good idea for those who want to answer a question, to not buy into the stated assumptions of the OP. They're often wrong.

Comment: **−1** This is **not the real code**, or alternatively, the description of it is a made-up one. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: when you are creating a linked list, use a sentry node. if you do, all special cases disappear. see http://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q

Answer (score 0):

The deletion of the last item of a list is a pretty simple algorithm.

You need to loop throught the whole list until you reach a node with the `next` pointer equals to `NULL`. This is your last element, the element you want to delete.

So you need to free the memory allocated by this object and set the `next` pointer for your previous item to `NULL`. This is the most important thing since it avoids to get segfaults.

Now, about the code you posted, I see you are doing something pretty bad.. you're declaring `*q` and `*p`, then looping throught your list (pointed by a global `Node* head`, I suppose).

The issue is that with the code in your loop you're unlinking the first item from the linked list and then the loop ends because You're copying the pointer `q` in `p` and then setting it's `next` pointer tu `Null` which leads to setting `q->next` to NULL. The first iterations goes **""fine""** leading you to have the first element with `next` set to `Null` the second iteration finds the `next` set to `Null` and thus it stops.

NOTE: Before posting the code solution I'd like to know if you have pretty clear in mind what the algorithm purpose is, try make an attempt to fix your code, if you can't do it again I'll post the correct algorithm :)